# What does offset do in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm following a webpage creation tutorial, and the instructor created a division with the class `.col-sm-offset-1`.
What does this do to the content within the div with that class?
Here's the complete code:

```html
<div class = "col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zmtmphtq/

Answer (score 34):

As per bootstrap 4.0 `.offset` class is available.

**1.** Use class `.offset` [See bootstrap offset documentaion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
</div>
```

**2.** Or use class `.mr` (margin-right) `.ml` (mrgin-left), [See bootstrap spacing documentaion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

```
`<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4 mr-5">col-4</div>
   <div class="col-4 ml-5">col-4</div>
</div>`
```

**3.** Or create a empty column as big as you want the offset to be

```
`<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col">col-4</div>
 </div>`
```

**4.** Or use .`mr-auto` to offset the next column

```
`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mr-auto">col-4</div>
    <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
 </div>`
```

[See the code in this codepen](https://codepen.io/morrissal/pen/wraKOy)

> **Note:** Bootstrap Alpha v4 does not have the `.offset` class, **Make sure to use Bootstrap 4.0**.

Answer (score 13):

In Bootstrap v4 you can use `offset-sm-1` like:

```html
<div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">...</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

In Bootstrap 3 `col-*-offset-*` will work to offset (move to the right) the column, but in Bootstrap 4 this has been changed to `offset-*-1`, so the markup would be:

`<div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">`

http://www.codeply.com/go/sbruTFHL6q

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the problem I was having. One of our offset classes was suddenly not working when upgraded to Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

Basically col-sm-offset-1 will leave amount of space on left and main content put towards right

you can also do this by giving margin-left also...

Answer (score 0):

you also have to remember to use the offset `offset-*` function with the same grid you make use of. e.g
`<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 text-center offset-lg-1"> some text here</div>`
or 
`<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-6 text-center offset-sm-1"> some text here</div>`
so as to keep the code clean

Answer (score 0):

Actually "offset-1" will leave space of one column on left and make main content towards right, but you can also achieved this by giving "mr" or "margin-right"

Answer (score 0):

```
mr-auto or ml-auto
```

Did the trick!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32654646)

Comment: @Blastfurnace who said thank you? I just added a different option

Comment: Your different option was already in the top-voted answer from 5 years ago.

Comment: But your criticism was over 'thank you', where??

Comment: Your answer has the same form as saying “that other answer did the trick”.  It’s not that complicated. I’m done with this conversation. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

Inaddition to@Morris you can also center the main column with `.mx-auto` so you don't need to use mr-auto and ml-auto together.

As said above in bootstrap 3 col offset was used to simulate a column so you don't need to create an empty col.